# RewriteRule lowercase transform for file names only

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to redirect Capital Case file names only to a lowercase file on the server, retaining intact directories case.

I don't have access to httpd.conf.

I have found [this](https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2012/11/force-lowercase-urls-rewrite-php/) that do the trick with php and RewriteRule but in my case I'm unable to capture the directories between `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']/base/` and `filename`, so I lost them in the redirection causing an apache fail.

The rules are:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# force url to lowercase if upper case is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
# ensure it is not a file on the drive first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (?=([^\/])*(\.htm|\.html|\.jpg))(.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$3 [QSA,L]
```

The RegEx `(?=([^\/])*(\.htm|\.html|\.jpg))(.*)` captures and passes only filename to the php script who makes the real redirect:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'])) {
    $url = $_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url'];
    unset($_GET['rewrite-strtolower-url']);
    $params = http_build_query($_GET);
    if(strlen($params)) {
        $params = '?' . $params;
    }
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/base/' . strtolower($url) . $params, true, 301);
    exit;
}
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die('Unable to convert the URL to lowercase. You must supply a URL to work upon.');
```

Example of URL I need to test is:

```
http://test.com/base/some Folder/some Other subfolder/Some-File-Name.jpg
```

Needed Result:

```
http://test.com/base/some Folder/some Other subfolder/some-file-name.jpg
```

Is there a way to correct things to capture the part of URL that I'm throwing out?

**Edit:** My entire .htaccess is visible [here.](https://gist.github.com/MassimoDIFA/afe0fbc081de5d4316e5)

Comment: Something like this? `^(.*\/)([^\/]+)(\.htm|\.html|\.jpg)$` https://regex101.com/r/hT8sM9/2

Comment: @maraca Your RegEx captures directories and domain name too, I would need to pass the directories to php but not perform transformations on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the exact example. You can get the full path in PHP as well. You don't need to capture the URI. You can use `REQUEST_URI` in PHP to get the full path. I would do something like this. 
Just send the full request to php and then handle it there.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

#don't do anything if php file is directly requested. 
RewriteRule ^rewrite-strtolower\.php - [L]

# force url to lowercase if upper case is found
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
# ensure it is not a file on the drive first
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule . /rewrite-strtolower.php [L]
```

//php file

```
<?php
if(isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])){

    $URI = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $URI = ltrim($URI,"/");
    $parts = explode("/",$URI);
    $filename = array_pop($parts);
    $URI = implode("/",$parts);

    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .'/'.$URI.'/'.strtolower($filename), true, 301);
    exit;

}
?>
```

Comment: yes this work fine, but in my entire scenery I have a lot of other RewriteRules that in this manner aren't performed. I have edited my question with a link to my htaccess. I have some more redirect rules handled by Redirection WP plugin, too.

Comment: Where did you put these rules?

Comment: just updated the gist. I have also noticed that the redirection inside htaccess are still performed but I lost the ones handled by WP Redirection plugin, how I can do? I have to put all of them in the rewrite-strtolower.php?

Comment: are these jpg files real or not?

Comment: real, they are in lowercase in the server and I will receive requests with them in Capitol Case, or with some character in UPPERCASE, jpg and html too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105063/discussion-between-lizardhr-and-panama-jack).